# Can you send info to an application without showing the notification in the status bar using GCM?

Tags: android, client-server, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to figure out a way to send data from a server to a particular android device having my app.so i came across Google cloud messaging service. i wanted to know if its possible to directly send information to my application on a phone from a php web application without showing a notification in the status bar? from all the examples Ive seen, it looks like a push notification is always sent. i would just like my app to directly receive the data without showing any push notification.is it possible? any help is gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have 100% control over what your application does upon receiving a push message. Looking at the [sample receive message code](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-receive), you can see that the `GcmIntentService` they build to handle the message can run any code you'd like - including or not including sending a notification.